# Log shipping, logs are copied to the second server folder but not uploaded to the database

Tags: sql-server, log-shipping

I am doing log shipping, but the second server is not uploading the logs to the secondary database.

I try to get the error but it doesn't reflect any. The jobs run without problems.

Any possible solution? Use official Microsoft documentation

I would appreciate it.

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server, they're completely different products..  Since you mentioned Microsoft documentation I removed the MySQL tag.

Comment: "I am doing log shipping" this is like saying "I am doing programming" :-) - it's possible the job on the "subscriber" side is not configured correctly or a job step is set to "quit with success" even if it fails. There's simply not enough information here for anyone to help.